# Trying to add a small subtitle under my title that is aligned to the left side of the title

Tags: html, css

Cheers! So I've got this page, you know? And I'm practicing some of this **html/css** stuff in my spare time, it looks fun, and I've got this title on my front page and I want to add a subtitle under it, that is aligned to the left of the title, but I've got no idea and I can't find it anywhere on the web. I've got knackered, and I'm no longer in the mood. I marked the place where I want to slap the text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="Anime-uri online, cu subtitrare în limba română." />
<meta name="author" content="Redd" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Taciturn | 沈黙寡言</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/bss.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                    <h1>沈黙寡言</h1>
                    <a class="button" href="/portal.php">Portal</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(/assets/img/biX0.jpg) no-repeat;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
.content {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #AE070A;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    font-size: 600%;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px #FFF;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #036AB1;
    font-size: 140%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: solid #036AB1 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #AE070A;
    border: solid #AE070A 3px;
}
/* Paragraph 
p {
    font-size: 160%;
    line-height: 210%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 3%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
 Paragraph */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content h1 {
        font-size: 250%;
    }
    .button {
        font-size: 110%;
        padding: 7px 15px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 100%;
        line-height: 160%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Seems like a nice addition. Can you edit your question and share what code you've currently got? Specifically the code surrounding the main title. That'll change how we can approach adding the subtitle.

Comment: I can't paste the code in, it just creates an html page in the editor, I'm new to the site and I have no idea why it does that. You can access the site if you want to see the code.

Comment: You do need to add the code - your website will change or not be available. Try looking at the `{}` button to help format the code in the editor here.

Comment: I got you. Paste your code in, highlight all of it then either click the Code Sample button in the editor or press Ctrl+K. It'll indent all of it with 4 spaces which will display it as code.

Comment: Alright mate I found out, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

align left in css will do, but you need put your sub title inside same code block.